# How to undo "Don't show this prompt again" in vscode python?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

Accidentally selected "Don't show this prompt again" when prompted to install Pylint in VSCode Python. How should I undo/reset the action so the prompt will appear again?

Answer (score 4):

To anyone coming here from Google, if you're looking to reset the `"Are you sure you want to move 'file' into 'folder'?"` prompt:

On macOS, open `/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json` and remove `"explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false`.

It's a similar process on Windows and Linux ✌️

Comment: Just press "Ctrl"+ "Shift" + P and open settings.json from vscode and change explorer.confirmDragAndDrop

Answer (score 3):

See the issue notes here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24815

You might have to do this:

- deinstall Visual Studio Code
- delete C:\Users[Username].vscode
- delete C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Code

or relevant paths on your operating system.

Comment: Add your observations to that issue linked above and someone can answer your question there.

Comment: One has to delete VS Code, that's a shame. The GitHub issue is locked to collaborators, so I can't add a comment to it. It hasn't seen activity since June 2021, so I'm guessing this will not be fixed any time soon 

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it on macOS without uninstalling VS Code or delete globalStorage:

1. Quit all VS Code instances (Cmd +Q)
2. Instal SQL Lite browser https://sqlitebrowser.org
3. Go to: /Users/[user_name]/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/ => Find the one that associate with your workspace that you previously clicked "Don't show this promt again" (by looking into workspace.json and identify the name)
4. Open stage.vscdb file with SQL Lite
5. Look for data key "ms-vscode.csharp"
6. Edit *"assetPromptDisabled":true* to  *"assetPromptDisabled":**false***
7. Save change
8. Reopen vs code

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/24815#issuecomment-547733206

Answer (score 0):

We can undo this behavior by going to setting, then search for "Confirm Delete".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).