# show "select a language" tip again after clicking "don't show" in vscode new file page

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I show the tip again on the top of the file if I click "don't show"?
[image]

I haven't click "don't show" yet cause I afraid I can't set it to show again

Comment: search `settings.json` for a possible setting or it is saved in the workspace config (binary files)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

open your settings in vs code and copy and paste it in your settings reset that workbench settings it is working perfectly.
[image: ****]

---

"workbench.editor.untitled.hint"

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct way to bring that specific menu up again.

However <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> will bring up the "search toolbar" and you can search for languages

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> will bring up the language selection

Comment: so this operation is irreversible?

Comment: Not sure, i always run through keyboard shortcuts on things. This doesnt answer your question but is along the same thread. Once you do click dont show, new tabs wont show it again.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770069/how-to-undo-dont-show-this-prompt-again-in-vscode-python which if you follow the links, possible leads to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/24815#issuecomment-474124799
Which is basically saying you may have to delete all the settings and reinstall to get that back. Again my vote is keyboard shortcuts