# VSCode | New Window select language

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: new untitled file message]

By mistake I pressed on "don't show this again". How can I make vscode show that option again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo "Don't show this prompt again" in vscode python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770069/how-to-undo-dont-show-this-prompt-again-in-vscode-python)

Comment: For future problems of unwanted settings change, press `ctrl shift p` then type in "`user settings json`". Then, find and delete the setting you changed, and it will revert to default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a setting that enables/disables that message:

`Workbench > Editor > Untitled: Hint`

By selecting "Don't show again" you disabled that setting (setting it to `hidden`).
To get the message back, reenable it - set it to `text`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press `ctrl + shift + P`
2. Type **Change Language Mode** press enter

You will get menu with all the languages.

Additionally you can save the file with correct extension to get all the language support installed in your VS code.

Hope this helped

Comment: You can also click the current language in the bottom-right corner ("plain text" on OP's screenshot).

Comment: Yep or do that.

Comment: thank you, but that's not what i wanted, if it's possible to bring back that message it will bee awesome!

Comment: Open settings.json using ```Ctrl+shift+P``` and select Preferences:Settings(JSON)

Find "workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden" change "hidden" to "text"

Comment: than you very much <3

Comment: I like using the `Ctrl+K` `M` combo

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I follow above answer I solved for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when they changed the name of this setting but now it's called

```
"workbench.editor.empty.hint"
```

You still need to change it to "text"