# How to disable default GitHub Copilot message in empty Jupyter notebook cells?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, github-copilot

I use GitHub Copilot and GitHub Copilot Chat extensions in VSCode. Recently, in empty cells of Jupyter notebooks, the following message started appearing:

[image]

> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> to ask GitHub Copilot Chat to do something. Start typing to dismiss.

I find it distracting and would like to disable it. How can I do that? Is there a dedicated option?

---

Update. The versions I currently use:

- VSCode v1.81.1 (2023-11-06)
- GitHub Copilot Chat v0.10.1 (Last updated 2023-11-06, 21:55:36);
- GitHub Copilot v1.135.0 (Last updated 2023-11-08, 13:01:28);

Comment: please add the exact version number of the Copilot Chat extension you have installed. I searched the code for 0.11.2023110702 and didn't find that string.

Comment: I updated my question with the version numbers. It seems that I use GitHub Copilot Chat v0.10.1

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

Use the `workbench.editor.empty.hint` setting.

Ordinarily, I'd vote to close this as a duplicate (of [VSCode | New Window select language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68958312/11107541)) for this reason, but I think there's some fun extra info that can be given for this particular question.

#### Listen to starball ramble

Ah ok. I needed to search differently: https://github.com/search?q=%22something+or+start+typing+to+dismiss.%22&type=code, which turns up [VS Code's https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/codeEditor/browser/emptyTextEditorHint/emptyTextEditorHint.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/codeEditor/browser/emptyTextEditorHint/emptyTextEditorHint.ts) in the `_getHintInlineChat` function (I.e. it's behaviour of VS Code and not of the GitHub Copilot extension in particular). At the time of this writing (VS Code 1.84), the line of code is:

```js
let ariaLabel = `Ask ${providerName} something or start typing to dismiss.`;
```

To disable the message, you could figure it out by guessing (or being familiar with VS Code settings), but let's do the fun way: there's a `_shouldRenderHint` function, and if you read it, you'll see it does `const configValue = this.configurationService.getValue(emptyTextEditorHintSetting);`, which is defined to `workbench.editor.empty.hint`. So there's your setting.

As for why it differs slightly from what you show in your question post, you mention you're on VS Code 1.81. The file was originally located at [src/vs/workbench/contrib/codeEditor/browser/untitledTextEditorHint/untitledTextEditorHint.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/release/1.81/src/vs/workbench/contrib/codeEditor/browser/untitledTextEditorHint/untitledTextEditorHint.ts), but interestingly, I don't see such a string template in there... I don't know.